# Using "n is odd if n=2k+1" , explain why 2n+7 is an odd integer.

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

Using "n is odd if n=2k+1", explain why 2n+7 is an odd integer.

I don't know if this is what is asked for, I would just say because 1 is an odd integer and 7 is an odd integer, 2n+7 has to be an odd integer.

Comment: If $n = 2k + 1$ and $k$ is an integer, $n$ is odd, not even.

Comment: oops, just changed it.

Comment: 2n+7 is odd no matter what n is, because 2n is even...?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're meant to rearrange $2n+7$ to have the form $2k+1$.

So
\begin{align*}
2n+7 &= 2n+6+1 \\
     &= 2(n+3)+1.
\end{align*}

Since $n+3$ is an integer, we conclude that $2n+7$ is odd.